# How to normalize Y axis in "histogram" function in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, axis

I am using histogram command to plot 3 histogram in one figure and I have completed function with histogram command and I dont want to rewrite it for old hist command. However Im unable to normalize Y axis, because h.Values vector is read only.

```
h=histogram(data,'Normalization','pdf');
h.Values=(h.Values-min(h.Values))/(max(h.Values)-min(h.Values);
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks

EDIT after first comment:
Yes I read matlab help. In the histogram image example I have PDF on Y axis, but values are from 0 to 3.5. I need to normalize from 0 to 1. When I use 'Normalization' parametr with 'probability' I get histogram from 0 to 0.3. I simply need PDF, but from 0 to 1.
[histogram example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3RyZ.png)

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html#input_argument_d0e415501

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use another 'new' function:

```
[y, x]=histcounts (x);
x=x(1:end-1)+diff(x/2)
```

Then you may normalize y as you wish. This function also has same normalize arguments as histogram.